# How to direct bash network request through a socket5 proxy?

Tags: bash, ssh, proxy, http-proxy

I know how to use `http_proxy` to redirect http request, but how to redirect the data with a socket5 proxy such as a SSH tunnel?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to redirect the output of a command through the network? Or to redirect an HTTP request through an SSH tunnel? Or something else? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

For bash network request to redirect through socket5 proxy, you have to export http_proxy variable:

`$ export http_proxy=socks5://username:passwd@socks5_proxy_ip:port`

Comment: This is unrelated to bash, it is up the the started application if to use or not the value of that variable.

Comment: I encourted the `Unsupported scheme `socks5'` error.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `tsocks` application, it is able to transparently redirect every network request of a controlled application through a given socks proxy.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could make it work reliably (on MacOS, but I expect bash behaves the same in unix/linux) was using proxychains.